# Symfony Composer create-project stucks at Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.0.*"

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I am trying to create new project using following command but it stops at last line for hours. I have pasted the output from command.
I have tried updating composer also.

```
$ composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project_name
```

The script began well

```
Creating a "symfony/website-skeleton" project at "./my_project_name"

Installing symfony/website-skeleton (v5.0.99)

  - Installing symfony/website-skeleton (v5.0.99): Loading from cache
Created project in C:\Users\Captain\Desktop\my_project_name
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/flex (v1.6.2): Loading from cache
Symfony operations: 1 recipe (2d3facef6986e76f376f76f911c83b03)
  - Configuring symfony/flex (>=1.0): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master

Loading composer repositories with package information

Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.0.*"
```

But nothing happens after this line.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. What happen when you launch this command in verbose mode? `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project_name -vvv --profile`

Comment: What is your php version? Ideally it should be 7.4.4.  Make sure you run "composer self-update" first.  You can also try to create again because Symfony uses what they call a flex server and sometimes the server hiccups.  If it just locking up then wait several minutes.  Sometimes create project is very fast.  Other times it can take awhile.  Finally, it is best to use the [Symfony CLI executable](https://symfony.com/download)  to create projects instead of directly using composer.

Comment: Hello Alexandre, the command mentioned by you worked but started with the error as follows: Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Running 1.10.5 (2020-04-10 11:44:22) with PHP 7.4.4 on Windows NT / 10.0

Comment: I'm also facing the same situation. Any solutions found?